# My animation export is distorted

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, export, add-on

[image]

My animation isn't exporting correctly. In blender everything seems fine even in the render window but when I add it to AE or PP it looks messed up.
I tried exporting in cycles and eeves but neither works, the animation is only 36 frames
I am using the camera with 15mm which I hadn't done before idk if that has anything to do with it. The character is from an add-on
I get this warning when I open the project

[image: how it looks in blender]

[image: how it looks in AE]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! can you share your blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: It sounds like you are successfully rendering.
Can you see the render results?
(i.e. image files)

Comment: Yes the second image is the render result, it's distorted